# SVG / CSS3 Transition issue in IE11 and Edge

Tags: html, css, svg, css-transitions

I have created the following radial wipe using a `transition` on the `stroke-dashoffset` property of an SVG:

[image]

This works fine in all major browsers with exception of IE11 and MS Edge. My project needs to support both of these browsers and CanIUse says both these browsers should support these declarations that I am using to achieve the effect. Why would IE11 and MS Edge be rendering the teal ring on `:hover` and `:focus` instantly, ignoring the  `transition` on the `stroke-dashoffset` property?

My code is as follows. Note that the `background-image` won't show up as it's not linked in the snippet.

```css
.avatar {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 2px;
    padding: 0.125rem;
    border: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
    border: 0.0625rem solid #c9c9c9;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
.avatar--m {
    width: 40px;
    width: 2.5rem;
    height: 40px;
    height: 2.5rem;
}
.avatar__border {
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    top: -0.0625rem;
    left: -1px;
    left: -0.0625rem;
}
.avatar--m > .avatar__border {
    width: 40px;
    width: 2.5rem;
    height: 40px;
    height: 2.5rem;
}
.avatar__border__stroke {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    stroke: #11a0ad;
    stroke-width: 1;
    fill: none;
    -webkit-transition: stroke-dashoffset 500ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: stroke-dashoffset 500ms ease-in-out;
    transition: stroke-dashoffset 500ms ease-in-out;
}
.avatar--m .avatar__border__stroke {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 20px 20px;
    -ms-transform-origin: 20px 20px;
    transform-origin: 20px 20px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 1.25rem 1.25rem;
    -ms-transform-origin: 1.25rem 1.25rem;
    transform-origin: 1.25rem 1.25rem;
    stroke-dasharray: 125.6636;
    stroke-dashoffset: 125.6636;
}
.avatar:hover .avatar__border__stroke {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
.avatar__image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
.avatar__image--male-1 {
    background: url(/static/media/avatar__image--male-1.8982bdbc.svg), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(17, 160, 173, 0.13), rgba(33, 208, 217, 0.13)), white;
    background: url(/static/media/avatar__image--male-1.8982bdbc.svg), -o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(17, 160, 173, 0.13), rgba(33, 208, 217, 0.13)), white;
    background: url(/static/media/avatar__image--male-1.8982bdbc.svg), linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(17, 160, 173, 0.13), rgba(33, 208, 217, 0.13)), white;
    background-position: center bottom -1px, 0;
    background-position: center bottom -0.0625rem, 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
    background-size: auto 85%, cover;
}

.badge {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 8px;
    min-width: 0.5rem;
    height: 24px;
    height: 1.5rem;
    padding: 0 8px;
    padding: 0 0.5rem;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 0.75rem;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.21);
    color: white;
    line-height: 24px;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-size: 0.6875rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.badge--error {
    background-color: #ed4a4a;
}
.avatar--m > .badge {
    position: absolute;
    top: -8px;
    top: -0.5rem;
    left: 24px;
    left: 1.5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a class="avatar avatar--m avatar--error" href="https://www.example.com" title="Charlie Winchester">
  <svg class="avatar__border" viewBox="0 0 40 40">
    <circle class="avatar__border__stroke" cx="20" cy="20" r="19.5"></circle>
  </svg>
  <div class="avatar__image avatar__image--male-1"></div>
  <span class="badge badge--error" unselectable="on">1k+</span>
</a>
```